# How to prevent wrapping string in quotes while enable auto-wrap in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I tend to enable auto-wrap :

```
:set textwidth=80
:set formatoptions+=wt
```

But I don't want to wrap when I input a long string in quotes when I coding with C or javascript, because it will be error;
Can I configure my vim auto-wrap exclude quotes?
or auto typing '\' before wrapping this line?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from this little script which I coded and add some improvements in order to fit your needs:

```c
"""""the event that will trigger the wrap (leaving insert mode)
au InsertLeave * call WrapLines()
"""""highlight the column where the wrapping will be made
set colorcolumn=30
"""""WrapLines will be executed on lines
function! WrapLines()
execute ":%g/^/ call WrapFunction()"
endfunction

"""""check and wrap the line
function! WrapFunction()
    let l:line=getline(".")
    let l:length=strlen(l:line)
    let l:occurence=0
    let l:i=0
    let l:nb=30
    for l:i in split(l:line,'\zs')
        if matchstr(l:i,'"') != ''
            let l:occurence+=1
    let l:occurence=l:occurence % 2
        endif

   let l:nb-=1
if l:nb == 0
break
endif
    endfor
    if l:length >= 30
        if l:occurence == 0
"""""to get ^M you need to type <ctrl-v><enter> buttons
            normal! 30|i^M
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

***Note:*** **to get the `^M` in the code please type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>**

Name and save the file **ex**:`script.vim` and call it after that by the command "`:source script.vim`"

Here is the example: ( **30** characters - Limit -):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your settings are wrapping the lines by adding carriage return and which cause problem while compiling.

Instead you can use the `wrap` option which is a **virtual wrap** and doesn't affect the lines:

```
:set wrap
:set textwidth=0
:set wrapmargin=0
```

Comment: I want to use a real wrap that affect the lines! But don't wrap a too long string inside quotes.

Comment: do youmean that wrapping will be in another real line ?

Comment: read about `:global` and `substitution` and events `autocmd` once you understand them fully you can solve this problem.

Comment: Tell me your progress. :)

Comment: Yes! My setting above has  wrap automatically when a line is more than 80  charactres! I just want to not wrap string inside quotes or add a '\' before auto-wraping.

Comment: What I mean is not wrap automatically a string which start a quote but has not be closed while this line' length is out of limit. And normally while this line's length is out of limit , it will automatically wrap.

Comment: exactly ! you have above the ingeredients start coding  ! It is not that too difficult but not easy too ! ;)

Comment: @Sword this "conditional" formatting could be achieved by enable auto formatting and a custom format expression or program. See the help for `auto-format`, `'fo` and `formatexpr`. It is a bit difficult though because what you're doing seems a bit unnatural. Either you chose to wrap your code or not. Many people auto wrap text but not code. I chose to limit my code width as well. But then, no strings are allowed to break the width either. Just create multiple strings and concatenate. In C, specially, things like `"my long" "string in three" "lines."` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yup,it is too difficult for me to complete it. I has given up the tiny function that occurred me.