# Highlighting the 70th character of a current line in Vim

Tags: vim, highlight, margins

I like to keep a strict 70 character margin whenever possible. To help with this, I want to configure vim so that the 70th character of the current line is highlighted. I understand that

```
set cursorline
```

can be used to highlight the current line. I, however, would like just the
very end of the line (the 70th character) to be highlighted. How would I go about accomplishing this?

**Edit:** cursorcolumn isn't what I'm looking for. I just want a single character (the 70th one on the current line).

**Edit 2:** perhaps a picture will help.[image]

Comment: Are you  intended in some how  to do something similar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41232730/4392605) ([**DEMO**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spxxg.gif)) ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス not really; your example leaves a highlighting trail. closer than cursorcolumn, though.

Comment: I bet what you want to do is not currently possible.

Comment: In case if you want this in order to wrap the text, try `:set textwidth=70` (it doesn't provide any highlighting but wraps the text) and `gq` in visual mode.

Comment: So the issue has more to do with highlighting beyond the newline character? In vim there exists a setting called `:set virtualedit=all`, which allows the cursor to be positioned where there is no actual character. Although, I have not seen a way to do any highlighting where there is no actual character.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `colorcolumn` to set a "right margin" bar.

This did not exist before Vim 7.3, so it is wisest to only enable it if the feature is available.

```
if exists('&colorcolumn')
    set colorcolumn=70
endif
```

I prefer that this only be shown in insert mode, so I use this:

```
if exists('&colorcolumn')
    autocmd InsertEnter * set colorcolumn=80
    autocmd InsertLeave * set colorcolumn=""
endif
```

That will set the option when you switch to insert mode, and turn it off when you leave insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * exe 'match IncSearch /\%70v\%' . line(".") . 'l./'
```

The highlight color will be determined by your color scheme.

You can change IncSearch to any of the highlight groups, which can be found by typing:

```
:hi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:call matchadd('Todo', '\%70c')
```

and if you don't want to count one tab as a single character, but you want to take into account all the spaces it takes:

```
:call matchadd('Todo', '\%70v')
```

You can use any other highlight group (for example to change color) listed by `:hi` instead of `Todo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VIM 7.3 you can set the color of a certain column with:

```
set colorcolumn=70
```